# How to change active tab to first css

Tags: css

Here is the code:

```
.tabs {
 float: right;
 position: relative; 
 min-height: 140px;
 margin: 25px 0;
 width: 500px;
}
.tab {
 float: left;
}
.tab label {
 background: #eee; 
 padding: 10px; 
 border: 1px solid #ccc; 
 margin-left: -1px; 
 position: relative;
 left: 1px; 
}
.tab [type=radio] {
 display: none; 
}
.content {
 position: absolute;
 top: 28px;
 left: 0;
 background: white;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 padding: 20px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc; 
}
[type=radio]:checked ~ label {
 background: white;
 border-bottom: 1px solid white;
 z-index: 2;
}
[type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .content {
 z-index: 1;
}
```

HTML structure:

```
<div class="tabs">
 <div class="tab">
 <input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1" checked>
 <label for="tab-1">Tab-1</label>
 <div class="content">
 bla-bla1
 </div>
 </div>

 <div class="tab">
 <input type="radio" id="tab-2" name="tab-group-1" checked>
 <label for="tab-2">Tab-2</label>
 <div class="content">
 bla-bla2
 </div>
 </div>

 </div>
```

This code makes the second tab is active. But I need the first tab. I don't really get in my mind what attributes should I change. The code structure for all tabs is the same, only the "id" attribute is different. If I add third tab, third tab will be active.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go: ***[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v79d5/)***

**HTML:**

```
 <input type="radio" id="tab-2" name="tab-group-1" /> // remove checked
```

**Explanation:** Since you have `checked` attributes applied to both input.

Answer (score 2):

Your tabs have radios:

```
<input type="radio" id="tab-2" name="tab-group-1" checked>
```

remove `checked` from all radios except first.

Answer (score 0):

[**Demo Link**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tp9A6/)

Only one tab at one time may be active.

When a tab is clicked it becomes an active tab.

If you need first tab to make active, add `checked` to only first tab. remove `checked` from others.

```
<input type="radio" id="tab-2" name="tab-group-1" checked/>
```